# Use Bootstrap Modal Confirmation to Delete List Items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a delete confirmation using bootstrap modal.  Everything works nicely except the modal always displays and deletes the first item in the list and not the actual list item where the delete button was clicked.  Can someone see where I am going wrong?

```
<table class="table">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DueDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Paid)
        </td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;width: 1px;">               
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Billing", new { id = item.InvoiceID })'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "InvoiceItem", new { id = item.InvoiceID })'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Details</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id=@item.InvoiceID><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Delete</button>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- The problem seems to be here:--> 
                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete invoice number: <b>@item.InvoiceID</b></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <form asp-controller="Billing" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id=@item.InvoiceID method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Delete</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The above view is loaded via script to avoid a page refresh with the below code when a dropdown is changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     


    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadPartial();
        $("#ddlCategory").change(loadPartial);
    });

    function loadPartial() {
        var companyID = $("#ddlCategory").val();
        var displayPaid = $("#chkDisplayPaid").is(':checked');
        var url = '@(Url.Action("InvoiceList", "Billing",null, null ))?companyID=' + companyID + '&displayPaid=' + displayPaid;
        $("#InvoiceList").load(url);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are repeating the same modal with same id in the loop which is wrong, a html page can't have duplicate id's, either change your modal `id="myModal"` to `id="@(i + 1)"` and `data-target="#(i +1 )"` and `foreach` loop to `for` loop as `@for(var i = 0; i > model.count() ; i++)`.

But this approach is wrong as you are repeating the modal for every row.

Instead of this, keep the modal outside to table and do it as below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{      
  ......rest same code                     
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id=@item.InvoiceID><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Delete</button>
  ....... rest same code     
 }
```

Put your modal out of the table and add input hidden field with id inside its form.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- The problem seems to be here:--> 
                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete invoice number: <b id="InvoiceID"></b></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <form asp-controller="Billing" asp-action="Delete" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
<input type="hidden" id="id">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Delete</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

`show.bs.modal` event fires on opening the modal.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);//Button which is clicked
            var clickedButtonId= button.data('Id');//Get id of the button
// set id to the hidden input field in the form.
           $("#InvoiceID").text(clickedButtonId);
           $("input #id").val(clickedButtonId);
    });
```

*If you like, for Edit and Detail you can open the same or different modal in the same page.

Comment: Wow, what an excellent reply - thanks I can see exactly that you mean.  The only thing I am not sure about it where to place the script.  As the above view is loaded via script to avoid a page refresh.  So I cant place the script inside the view as it wont be loaded and placing it on the main view is doesn't fire.  I edited my original post to show the script I use to  load the view without refreshing the page.

Comment: When I place the code there it does not fire when the modal is opened.

Comment: $("#InvoiceList").load( url, function() { //do write script here });

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I had another problem which was that I had clashing jquery javascript source files.

Comment: Jquery file clashing with what? Are you using two diffrent versions of jquery at same time or is it clashing with bootstrap?

Comment: I had two different versions of jquery at the same time.

Comment: But why you doing so? Choose any one.

Comment: Yes I am now thanks.  I deleted one yesterday and the code works fine.  I was just pointing out that I also had another issue getting my code to work, before that I wrongly though it was something wrong with the code you posted.